# Keywords "(2016)" to use to convert structure database to be not begining but end of the line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to format database use keywords e.g. **(2016)**  in editors  Notepad++  and convert /format un-ordered structure to be at the end of each line!
**Here is before extract sample:**
 `Airbourne - Breakin' Outta Hell (2016) Anger Rising - Come Hell Or High Water (2016) Black Star Furies - Vamp In Paradise (2016) Black Swamp Water - Chapter One (2016) Blues Pills - Golden Treasures (2016) Cactus - Black Dawn (2016)Captain Frapat - Coming Home (2016) Cornerstone - Reflections (2016) Crystal Ball - Déjà-Voodoo (2016)Delain - Moonbathers 2CD (2016) Edge Of Broken - Dare To Dream (2016)` 
**and in desire result after using regex in Notepad++ example word (2016) to be at the end of each line- not beginning of the line!**
**Sample like that:** 
 `Airbourne - Breakin' Outta Hell (2016)
Anger Rising - Come Hell Or High Water (2016)
Black Star Furies - Vamp In Paradise (2016)
Black Swamp Water - Chapter One (2016)
Blues Pills - Golden Treasures (2016)
Cactus - Black Dawn (2016)
Captain Frapat - Coming Home (2016)
Cornerstone - Reflections (2016)
Crystal Ball - Déjà-Voodoo (2016)
Delain - Moonbathers 2CD (2016)
Edge Of Broken - Dare To Dream (2016)`

Comment: Find [`([^(]+\([^(]*\))\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/rH4LUF/1) and replace with `$1\n`

Comment: Do you want a linebreak only after `(2016)` or after any year?

Comment: @Toto thanks for the question - You mean that if I use this as year (2016), or (2014)  can be expressed more global in regex?

Comment: Yes, I do. See my answer below, is that what you want?

Comment: @Toto Thanks for the help and give me a more visual explanation in an example for better understanding-regex for job breaking line in un-ordered unformatted data before and after any keywords -like  You give me b4- Thx for support-If I get 15 points-(  somebody vote down) I will vote up your explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\(2016\)\h*`     or `\(\d+\)\h*` for any year
- Replace with: `$0\n`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\(      : open parenthesis
2016    : literally "2016" or \d+ : 1 or more digits
\)      : close parenthesis
\h*     : 0 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0      : whole match, ie. (2016) or (year)
\n      : line break (you could use \r\n if requested)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Airbourne - Breakin' Outta Hell (2016) 
Anger Rising - Come Hell Or High Water (2016) 
Black Star Furies - Vamp In Paradise (2016) 
Black Swamp Water - Chapter One (2016) 
Blues Pills - Golden Treasures (2016) 
Cactus - Black Dawn (2016)
Captain Frapat - Coming Home (2016) 
Cornerstone - Reflections (2016) 
Crystal Ball - Déjà-Voodoo (2016)
Delain - Moonbathers 2CD (2016) 
Edge Of Broken - Dare To Dream (2016)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following regular expression:

- `(.+?\s\(2016\))`

(there can be more easier way ), but don't I normally don't put much effort on *one time* task, which I assume this is same case for you as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
(.+?)(\(\d+\))\s*
```

And replace this with

```
$1$2\n
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/SXTjcv/1/).

Comment: Thanks for link- I never used that online to solve -good beginning to start!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to find :

```
([^)(]*)(\([\d]+\))\s*
```

and this to replace:

```
\1\2\n
```

Live demo [here](http://regexr.com/3h0nd)

Comment: Good link for testing result and further learning regex- thx for reply